# I tested in my SQL Developer one case about "Subquery in Order By"

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

I have question about "Subquery in Order by clause". The below request returns the error. Is it means that Subquery in Order by clause must be scalar?

```
select * 
from employees
order by (select * from employees where first_name ='Steven' and last_name='King');
```

Error:

> ORA-00913: too many values
>   00913. 00000 -  "too many values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means that if you use a subquery in `ORDER BY` it must be scalar.

With `select *` your subquery returns multiple columns and the DBMS would not know which of these to use for the sorting. And if you selected one column only, you would still have to make sure you only select one row of course. (The difference is that Oracle sees the too-many-columns problem immediately, but detect too many rows only when fetching the data.)

This would be allowed:

```
select * from employees
order by (select birthdate from employees where employee_id = 12345);
```

This is a scalar query, because it returns only one value (one column, one row). But of course this still makes as little sense as your original query, because the subquery result is independent from the main query, i.e. it returns the same value for every row in the table and thus no sorting takes effect.

A last remark: A subquery in `ORDER BY` makes very seldomly sense, because that would mean you order by something you don't display. The exception is when looking up a sortkey. E.g.:

```
select *
from products p
where type = 'shirt' and color = 'blue' and size in ('S', 'M', 'L', 'XL')
order by (select sortkey from sizes s where s.size = p.size);
```

Comment: Thaks for accepting. Please see that I added an example for a reasonable subquery in `ORDER BY` just now.

Comment: Thanks you again. If I correctly understand your example this is correlated subquery. İt turns out that the subquery in order by can be correlated as well? Am I right?

Comment: Yes this is a correlated subquery and as mentioned a non-correlated subquery in `ORDER BY` even makes no sense, as it returns the same value everytime, so it has no effect on the sort order at all.

Answer (score 1):

It means that [valid options](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) for `ORDER BY` clause can be

- expression,
- position or
- column alias

A subquery is neither of these.